# Photoshop: A5 paper size in portrait mode

Tags: printing, photoshop

I have to do some design work for A5 paper size  in Photoshop in portrait mode , i tried to google about it but could not find information  that could help me about it  i found things like this

```
Dimensions:
inches: 8.264 w x 5⅚
```

can someone help me with it  what should be width and height of document in A5 size in portrait mode

Comment: Click `File`->`New`->`Document Type`->`International Paper`->`A5`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not about programming as stated in the [help/on-topic]. It may better fit on [graphicdesign.se].

Answer (score 0):

At 300 ppi (pixels per inch) the image needs to be 1748 x 2480 pixels.